# css styling background: url isn't working

Tags: css

I'm trying to set a background image from server like so

```
 background: url('img/menrainbow.jpg')
```

but it won't work however when I replace the url with an image url with a domain it does. Can I call the image url with the domain like

```
 background: url(mydomain.com/imagepath)
```

Comment: The path must be relative to the CSS file .... check that

Comment: omg duh I placed the image in the root folder >___< lulz